# Titanium Studio not building android application

Tags: android, android-emulator, titanium

I recently moved to titanium android development. i was trying to install titanium studio on my windows 8 machine and followed official site instructions.

1) I installed java 1.7 sdk (on C:\Program Files (x86)\Java) 
2) Downloaded and installed latest titanium studio 
3) Downloaded the latest android sdk 
4) and created JAVA_HOME variable (C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_21) 
5) added (C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin) to path varable 
6) added android path to PATH enviorment variable

And tried to create a simple project and run it on emulator  but i am getting [image]errors

So i tried to run on my device and it gives different kind of error

[image]

Please Guide me to solve this issue....

Comment: Did you try cleaning the project and check?

Comment: yes i tried to clean my project and imported existing working project but no luck....

Comment: Which version of Titanium are you using?

Comment: Latest version 3.1.0.201304151600

Answer (score 0):

link to similar problem over on the appcelerator q&a: https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/152497/titanium-sdk-310-error-typeerror-argument-of-type-nonetype-is-not-iterable-on-building-android-app

looks to be related to the android tools being is a different location than expected